# Adding a Sublayout to a MVC Placeholder (PageEditor)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

is it possible to add an existing sublayout (ascx) to a sitecore mvc placeholder in the pageeditor? If I add it, nothing happens but there is no error at all.

What does work is the following in my view:

```
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("Dummy.ascx");}
```

Sitecore will render that sublayout, but if the ascx file has another sublayout nested, it will not get rendered.

Dummy.ascx:

```
      <sc:Sublayout Path="AnotherSublayout.ascx" runat="server" />
```

AnotherSublayout is not visible at all.

Comment: This is not something supported out of the box, but apparently, there are workarounds. Have you seen these blog posts? 1) [**Using Sitecore MVC components on WebForms pages**](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2012/december/mvc-webforms.aspx); 2) [**Mixing Sublayout with Rendering**](http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/09/15/mixing-sublayout-with-rendering-webforms-with-mvc-request/).

Comment: Thanks for the links I will have a look at it.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko you should change your comment into an answer. +1

Comment: @MarekMusielak Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is not something supported out of the box, but there are workarounds. Please take a look at the following blog posts:

- [Using Sitecore MVC components on WebForms pages](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2012/december/mvc-webforms.aspx)
- [Mixing Sublayout with Rendering – Webforms with MVC request](http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/09/15/mixing-sublayout-with-rendering-webforms-with-mvc-request/)

Comment: Although this most likely answers the question, it might be qualified as "link-only" answer on SO. Hence, it's a good idea to copy the most appropriate snippet to the answer's body. In case the original links deprecate, the answer will still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the concept Usercontrol renderings in a Sitecore MVC website.
[This topic](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2014/02/11/usercontrol-renderings-in-a-sitecore-mvc-website-wffm-for-mvc/) will help you do.